# Optimize SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get distinct of two columns from a SQL Server table. I am getting this result - can I optimize this query?

```
create TABLE #Temporary_tbl
(                              
    ProductColour VARCHAR(50),
    ProductSize VARCHAR(20),
)

insert into #Temporary_tbl (ProductColour)
   select distinct productcolour
   from shoptransfer

insert into #Temporary_tbl (ProductSize)
   select distinct ProductSize
   from shoptransfer

select * from #Temporary_tbl
```

I try this :

```
select distinct ProductColour, null as ProductSize
from shoptransfer

union all

select distinct null as ProductColor, ProductSize
from shoptransfer
```

Comment: Your query is fine.  What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your expectation: I'm guessing want one distinct list of Colours and one distinct list of Sizes, but then you want them to appear in the same results table, like this:

```
Colour      Size
blue        10
green       12
orange      14
```

even though there's no relationship between blue & size 10, etc. This isn't a great presentation of the data, because what happens when there are 5 colours but 100 sizes.

You could do this by selecting each of the DISTINCT lists separately along with a ROW_NUMBER() and then join on the row numbers. It's not really what SQL is there for, but I can understand sometimes you want to do this sort of thing for reporting reasons.

eg

```
select productSize, productColour
from ( 
    -- get the colours and a row number
    select productColour, row_number() over ( order by productColour ) as rownum
    from ( select distinct productColour from shoptransfer ) as c1
) as colours
-- full outer join so the row numbers match and you get all the rows from both
full outer join ( 
    -- get the sizes and a row number
    select productSize, row_number() over ( order by productSize ) as rownum
    from ( select distinct productSize from shoptransfer ) as s1
) as sizes
on colours.rownum = sizes.rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 select  ProductColour  , null as ProductSize
 from shoptransfer
 GROUP BY ProductColour

 union all

 select  null as ProductColor, ProductSize
 from shoptransfer
 GROUP BY ProductSize
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

depends how you want to present data here other suggestion maybe + PIVOT

```
   select * from (
    SELECT  distinct       
     [ProductColor] as 'tata_column', 'ProductColor' as 'P_TAG'    
    FROM shoptransfer
 union all
     SELECT  distinct
     [ProductSize] as 'data_colunm'  , 'ProductSize' as 'P_TAG'
   FROM shoptransfer
   ) A
```

I will eliminate TEMP tables to run it faster

Please note that USING "WITH CLAUSE" with HUGE RECORDS SET WILL SLOW DOWN and maybe crash the server!!!